# Pass multilevel object method as a parameter

Tags: java

If my method call is:

```
obj.getLevelOne().getLevelTwo().getValue();
```

And I want to pass this method as a parameter below:

```
boolean checkValue( obj, method , value) 
{
   return obj.method() == value;
}
```

I want to call the checkValue method like this:

```
checkValue(obj, "getLevelOne().getLevelTwo().getValue", value);
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this? Please help.

Comment: Your question is very foggy! Please, try to explain what do you want better.

Comment: Please check now? and let me know if you still think question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do something like this, i recommend either:

1.use a Callable and create anonymous subclasses.  NOTE: this is somewhat similar to the approach given above with "MyGetter", except that it uses Callable.  There's no need for our own interface, since we can use something that was intended for this purpose that's built into the jdk.

> ```
> public <T> boolean checkValue(Callable<T> valueGetter, T value) {
>     return value.equals(valueGetter.call());
> }
>
> final MyObject obj = new MyObject();
> checkValue(new Callable<String>() { 
>      public String call() { return obj.getLevelOne().getLevelTwo().getValue(); }
> }, "foo");
> ```

2.using some sort of EL package (mvel works well as an embedded library).

You could then do:  "levelOne.levelTwo.value" as your expression, and use mvel to evaluated in on "obj".

```
public <T> boolean checkValue(Object obj, String expression, T value) {
    Object objVal = MVEL.eval(expression, obj);
    return value.equals(objVal);
}
checkValue(obj, "levelOne.levelTwo.value", "foo");
```

Of course, the first one is much more typesafe, though your "expression" would be done at compile time since you're explicitly coding it into the callable implemention.  The second approach is more dynamic and lets you compute the expression at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I solved this problem just like the 2nd approach you suggested. However I wrote my own invoiceMethod(expression, object) . :)

Answer (score 3):

In java Functions are not a first class concept (yet, coming in Java 8). So it's not possible to pass a method as you can in many other languages that have functional concepts.

What you need to do instead is declare an interface and implement it using an anonymous inner class. e.g.

**The Interface**

```
interface MyGetter {
    Object doGet();
}
```

**The Check Method**

```
boolean checkValue(MyGetter getter, Object value) {
    return getter.doGet().equals(value);
}
```

**The Call**

```
checkValue(new MyGetter() {
    public Object doGet() {
        return obj.getLevelOne().getLevelTwo().getValue();
    }
}, 5);
```

What we're actually doing in the call is creating a new class and an object of that type to make the actual call you need.

Edit:

If you need different return types you can make the interface and check method generic, e.g.

**The Interface**

```
interface MyGetter<T> {
    T doGet();
}
```

**The Check Method**

```
<T> boolean checkValue(MyGetter<? extends T> getter, T value) {
    return getter.doGet().equals(value);
}
```

**The Call**

```
checkValue(new MyGetter<SomeClass>() {
    public SomeClass doGet() {
        return obj.getLevelOne().getLevelTwo().getValue();
    }
}, 5);
```

Comment: So this way we need to have all the possible getters we want in the interface right?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to do I'm afraid. What we're doing is introducing a layer of abstraction, so you taylor the interface to provide the information required by the check method. The purpose of the anonymous inner class is to adapt the class where the data is to match what is required for the interface. If you need different return types then you could use a generic signature, see the example I've added above.

Comment: Functions ARE NOT a first class object in java 8.  There is only syntactic sugar in the compiler to allow you to easily implement an interface with a single defined method.  You create a lamba in java 8, and it becomes an instance of the interface you are assigning it to (or the declared argument you are passing it as).